# Break from a loop when math.random generates number between interval

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to make a function, that creates an array and breaks the cycle when Math.random generates a number between interval (x,y) to be exact, the numbers must be -110 and 110. For me, it just generates numbers and doesn't break the cycle.

```
let reiksmes=[];

for(let i=0; i<20; i++){
    reiksmes.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)-500);
 
    if (reiksmes >= -110 && reiksmes <= 110){
       break; 
    }
```

Comment: `if (reiksmes >= -110 && reiksmes <= 110)` is checking if *the array* `reiksmes` is more than -110 or less than 110. What you want to check is the last item in the array. Or in other words, the last thing that was generated (and then added)

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: `const v = Math.floor(...); reiksmes.push(v); if (v >= -110 && v <= 110) break; `

Comment: as you're pushing to the array and it starts empty, `reiksmes[i]` would do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, generate a value and push it into the array. If it is in the required range, break out of the loop.

```
let reiksmes=[];

for(let i=0; i<20; i++){
    newValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) - 500;
    reiksmes.push(newValue);

    if (newValue >= -110 && newValue <= 110){
       break; 
    }
```

Also using **magic numbers** such as -110 or 110 is definitely not a good practice. Store them as constants instead.